# Failed to install WPF in client PC - 0x80073CFD

Tags: wpf, powershell, uwp, dependencies

I have an internal WPF application to be installed in client's PC.
Usually I start with the installation of these three dependency files

```
Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2.appx
Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.2.appx
Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.appx
```

Then, I need to install the `appxbundle` file to complete the installation.
But this client's PC don't have app installer and I was told to run PowerShell as administrator for installation. The command I used was

```
Add-AppxPackage -Path "file location/file"
```

I managed to install the dependency files but I couldn't install the appxbundle file.
The error appeared was as below

> Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFD, A Prerequisite for an
> install could not be satisfied

How should I go about solving this error? For it only happens when the installation is done using PowerShell.

Comment: Read the actual installation log for more details, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/Get-AppxLastError?view=win10-ps

Comment: So to be clear...is this a new error? If so what in the code has changed since you last had a working version...what is new in other words?

Comment: @ΩmegaManThis The latest version is the working version. It works well in other users' PC (can install successfully using the same dependency files and appxbundle file using the apps installer and the application can run smoothly). This error only appears when I have to use the PowerShell to install

Comment: Ok, so you have never installed this using PowerShell. Correct? It appears you are missing a library which you imply is not from the app; if so the one of the `CoreFramework.Debug` or `CoreRuntime` or `VCLibs.x64.Debug`.... is missing a prerequisite.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan But I managed to install all 3 dependecies. I think I cant install them properly if any of them is missing a prerequisite. Do you think the prerequisite is missing for the appxbundle?